# How can I warm up my budgies cage in winter?

Tags: birds, parrots, junior-pets, budgerigar

I have four pairs of budgies. The cage is kept outdoor. Now its winter. I don,t know what to do to keep my birds warm and cozy. The cage is big and I can,t move it indoor. I cover the cage every night with cloth. But I think it is not of much help. My question is what is the best way to keep my budgies warm and cozy in winter?

Comment: How cold does it actually get at night where you live? And please forgive me for being blunt did you take responsibility for 8 animals without having a plan how to properly care for them?

Comment: At night it gets 10 to 12  degrees Celsius. And I did not take responsibility of 8 animals without planning. What is wrong if I seek some advice from someone on taking care for them?

Comment: On the contrary! Asking for advice is a thousand times better than letting animals suffer because of a lack of knowledge. But without further information your question reads kind of strange. My first impression was that you *somehow* adopted 8 birds with their big cage and now don't know how to care for them. Anyway, your question is absolutely valid and I apologize for my choice of words.

Comment: There is nothing to apologize for.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a gentle heat lamp (ensuring the actual heating elements, which can burn, can't be touched by animals), or use rubber hot water bags or heated socks full of rice (you can microwave these) covered with cloth in a way that is safe and appealing to them! Online you may be able to find heat pads that hold heat better than water/rice, and there are electrical-powered heat pads if you have an outlet nearby.